# ASP NET Core Web API disable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 support

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, .net-5, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to disable the TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 support for an API running on docker (Debian OS) and .NET 5. I found this code related to this specific problem:

```
     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
                    {
                        opt.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(s =>
                        {
                            s.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
                        });
                    }).UseStartup<Startup>();
                }
            );
```

However, when publishing the changes, I am running a script to determine if the TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 are still supported by the server, and surprisingly although I am explicitly setting the HTTPS defaults to TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 I get the following results:
[image]

here is the Powershell script:

```
 $HostName = 'YOUR_URL'
 $Port = '443'
 
 $RetValue = New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Host = $HostName
            Port = $Port
            SSLv2 = $false
            SSLv3 = $false
            TLSv1_0 = $false
            TLSv1_1 = $false
            TLSv1_2 = $false
            TLSv1_3 = $false
            KeyExhange = $null
            HashAlgorithm = $null
        }
        "ssl2", "ssl3", "tls", "tls11", "tls12","tls13" | %{
            $TcpClient = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
            $TcpClient.Connect($RetValue.Host, $RetValue.Port)
            $SslStream = New-Object Net.Security.SslStream $TcpClient.GetStream(),
                $true,
                ([System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback]{ $true })
            $SslStream.ReadTimeout = 15000
            $SslStream.WriteTimeout = 15000
            try {
                $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($RetValue.Host,$null,$_,$false)
                $RetValue.KeyExhange = $SslStream.KeyExchangeAlgorithm
                $RetValue.HashAlgorithm = $SslStream.HashAlgorithm
                $status = $true
            } catch {
                $status = $false
            }
            switch ($_) {
                "ssl2" {$RetValue.SSLv2 = $status}
                "ssl3" {$RetValue.SSLv3 = $status}
                "tls" {$RetValue.TLSv1_0 = $status}
                "tls11" {$RetValue.TLSv1_1 = $status}
                "tls12" {$RetValue.TLSv1_2 = $status}
                "tls13" {$RetValue.TLSv1_3 = $status}
            }
            # dispose objects to prevent memory leaks
            $TcpClient.Dispose()
            $SslStream.Dispose()
        }
        $RetValue
```

Is this a bug on Kestrel Configuration? Can I do something else to disable TLS1.0 and TLS1.1 encryptions?

**EDIT** This is the original issue that I am trying to solve:

*The remote service accepts connections encrypted using TLS 1.0. TLS 1.0 has a number of cryptographic design flaws. Newer versions of TLS are designed against these flaws and should be used whenever possible.
PCI DSS v3.1 requires that TLS 1.0 be disabled entirely by June 2018, except for point-of-sale terminals and their termination points.
As of March 31, 2020, Endpoints that aren't enabled for TLS 1.2 and higher will no longer function properly with major web browsers and major vendors.*

Comment: Do not get TLS version and encryption mode confused.  Every version of TLS supports multiple encryption modes.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Comment: Maybe your Power Shell Script is bad!  It looks like the status return only indicates that you did not get an exception.  It doesn't mean the TLS version actually gave good results.

Comment: @jdweng, thanks for your comment. Yeah, it doesn't throw an exception, and that means that the remote server still accepts connections encrypted with TLS1.0 and TLS1.1

Comment: Are you sure?  Just because a connection fails to complete doesn't, doesn't mean you are going to get an exception.  You may just get a null or an error status.

Comment: I mean, if the encryption is not supported, it should throw an error, right? It does throw an error for ssl and TLS1.3, why it would be different for TLS1.0 and TLS1.1? Not sure how else to test if those encryptions are still available

Comment: It may have something to do with a security push Microsoft did in June 2020 on servers.  Microsoft disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1.  So being disabled may return a different response in the TLS protocol than if the authentication fails.

Comment: Yeah, not sure, we are using Debian containers + kestrel, but who knows? Thanks again @jdweng for your comments.

Comment: In my case the load balancer from AWS influenced this

Comment: Do you mean load balancer or do you mean the Proxy?

Comment: The actual ELB from AWS has an encryption that can be configured. In my case the ELB was configured to allow TLS1.0 & TLS 1.2 . Once I've updated that to only accept TLS1.2 this script was showing that only TLS1.2 is accepted

Comment: TLS 1.0 and 1,2 have been obsolete since 2019.  Only TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are valid.  TLS is a word in OS where each version is a bit.  Best to set to either 1.2 'OR' 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Since .net 5 it seems that the option to disable TLS version was removed, instead it has to be disabled in the OS.

> Kestrel now uses the system default TLS protocol versions rather than
> restricting connections to the TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 protocols like it
> did previously.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed

Then the question might become: how do you disable that in a docker image using Debian, it seems that it can be done by a docker RUN OpenSSL command in the dockerfile, to disable it in OpenSSL or in the config file of OpenSSL.

**How to disable TLS v1.0 and TLS v1.1 in OpenSSL**

In /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf after oid_section add:

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

https://blog.surgut.co.uk/2019/08/how-to-disable-tls-10-and-tls-11-on.html